# Is it possible to set up browser for not displaying images for the certain Cypress test

Tags: request, cypress

I need to check several filters on the page heavily populated with images. The filters check images text only, so I would like to set up the browser for not displaying the images to speed up the test execution. Is it possible in Cypress?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways, but it depends on how the page displays the images.

If it fetches them from an API, use `cy.intercept()` to catch the call to the API and stub the response

Check the network tab of dev-tools for fetches that load the images.

General pattern,

```js
cy.intercept('/url-fetching-images', {})
```

May need adjusting if URL's vary per image - you can add wildcard chars.

Comment: I could intercept the request, but anyway the test would need to wait until the response is finished and the new filter could be applied, which means that the same time would be spent. The test itself does not take too much time. But page downloading is too much time consuming.

Comment: No, if you use a stub the request is never sent to the server. The stub response is returned immediately.

Comment: The only thing that may be a problem is what should the stub value be. Above I used an empty object `{}` which is simplest.

Comment: If I create a stub it will not test filter as I need to provide a stub with my own data, but not the real server response is not it?

Comment: Hmm, so question lacks some details - are you saying the response contains the text you want to test? You need to investigate the request format and post it. It's possible to modify parts of a response.

Comment: I need to test if the filter was applied properly and only those elements are displayed which match the filter requirements